# Ubuntu 20.04 - Running 3 commands on terminal after startup (any stay open )

Tags: bash, scripts

After reboot I need 3 terminals open, running a MQTT subscriptions.

For that I divide to process into 2 segments: 1) a `.sh` file, running those subscriptions, and 2) executing after reboot.

**Part 1 -`mqtts.sh` file**

```
#! /bin/bash

gnome-terminal --tab -- mosquitto_sub -u "guy" -P "1234" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/Messages"
gnome-terminal --tab -- mosquitto_sub -u "guy" -P "1234" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/log"
gnome-terminal --tab -- mosquitto_sub -u "guy" -P "1234" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/debug"
gnome-terminal -- mosquitto_pub -u "guy" -P "1234" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/All" -m "status"
```

When I execute this file, 3 new tabs gets opened displaying subscriptions as needed.

Question 1: How to edit each tab's title ?

**Part 2 - Running at startup**

I tried several options:

1. Adding a `cron` job using `sudo crontab -e`, adding `@reboot` /home/guy/Documents/mqtts.sh`.**FAILED**
2. Adding `/etc/rc.local` a line `/home/guy/Documents/mqtts.sh || exit 1`.**FAILED**

Question 2: What is wrong with ways 1,2 that failed?

Guy